Plutus Playground and Marlowe Playground Are Down — Any Updates?
I've noticed that both the Plutus Playground and Marlowe Playground are currently down and inaccessible. Does anyone have information on why these services are unavailable and when they might be back online? Are there any ongoing maintenance or updates that we should be aware of?
I rely on these tools for testing and developing smart contracts, so any insights or official updates would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
